# JavaFX on ARM running jdk1.8.0

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, arm

I know that Oracle removed JavaFX in 8u33, but I'm wondering why I can't use JavaFX with jdk1.8.0? I got it from the Oracle archives (http://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/8-b132/jdk-8-linux-arm-vfp-hflt.tar.gz)

I have this extracted in `/usr/bin/java_8_arm/jdk1.8.0` and am running my .jar file with `sudo /usr/bin/java_8_arm/jdk1.8.0/bin/java -jar jarfile.jar`

Running `/usr/bin/java_8_arm/jdk1.8.0/bin/java -version` returns

```
java version "1.8.0"
Java (TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot (TM) client VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```

and running `System.out.println("Running Java version: " + Runtime.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion());`

returns `Running Java Version: 1.8.0`

The error I'm getting is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel
    at front_end.GUI.initGUI(GUI.java:47)
    at back_end.Run.main(Run.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
```

If you're wondering, I'm programming and compiling the program to a shared file via Windows 7 and running the JAR from a Raspberry Pi.

inb4 "why do you need javafx on a raspberry pi" - to render html, since other java components only support html 3.2. I have tried other renderers. This is the only one I could even get working right on my desktop, let alone the RPi.

Also, I am programming and compiling on 1.8.0 as well.

UPDATE:

As per José Pereda's answer, I have downloaded the JavaFX files and placed them in my original java install (I am now using `/usr/bin/jdk8u6/` as my folder, and obviously `jdk1.8.0_06`).

Here is my install hierarchy, starting from the `lib` directory:

```
/usr/bin/jdk8u6/lib/:
arm ext             javafx.properties  jfxswt.jar  tools.jar
ct.sym  ir.idl              jconsole.jar       orb.idl
dt.jar  javafx.platform.properties  jexec          sa-jdi.jar

/usr/bin/jdk8u6/lib/arm:
jli          libgstreamer-lite.so        libjfxmedia.so
libdecora_sse.so     libjavafx_font_freetype.so  libjfxwebkit.so
libfxplugins.so      libjavafx_font_pango.so     libprism_common.so
libglass_monocle.so  libjavafx_font.so       libprism_es2_eglfb.so
libglass_monocle_x11.so  libjavafx_iio.so        libprism_es2_monocle.so
libglass.so      libjawt.so          libprism_sw.so

/usr/bin/jdk8u6/lib/arm/jli:
libjli.so

/usr/bin/jdk8u6/lib/ext:
jfxrt.jar
```

I still get the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download an updated and upgraded version of JavaFX for ARM from here: [JavaFX Embedded SDK](http://gluonhq.com/labs/javafxports/downloads)

Once downloaded on your Raspberry Pi, you'll need to extract and copy the content into your JDK 1.8 (check this [link](http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/#anchor-1) for embedded).

You will be able to run the latest JavaFX version *for ARM** on your Pi, including the WebView control.

Also, using the Gluon plugin for your IDE, you'll be able to deploy [remotely](http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/#_embedded_3) the project on your Pi as well.

**EDIT**

*ARM: Note that JavaFX for ARM has never supported Swing. Other features like the WebView and Media weren't supported either, but recently these have been included in Gluon's build.

Comment: Thanks for the bit about deploying remotely, I might use that. As for the rest, testing now

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention: Swing was never supported in JavaFX for ARM, but since you are using JavaFX with a WebView, can you use it?

Comment: Also, try to update the JDK to a more recent version

Comment: This won't work either way because my application needs swing with javafx. I would move the files to my newer jdk, but it shipped with Raspbian and I have no idea where the base install is

Comment: Although it did not solve my problem, I will mark this as accepted because it explained why what I want to do is not possible without cross-compiling swing into the build. I will think of another solution.