# JavaFX Webkit on Raspberry Pi 2 / Raspbian Jessie

Tags: javafx, raspberry-pi2, gluon

I installed JavaFX (OpenJFX, Gluon JavaFX Embedded SDK  8.60.7)  with the help of this thread [JavaFX on ARM running jdk1.8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38102348/javafx-on-arm-running-jdk1-8-0/38103442#38103442) onto a Java8 SDK. I can execute simple JavaFX applications now. But when i use the WebView, the following error occurs:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ./jdk1.8.0_91/jre/bin/java -jar fxtest.jar
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: You have loaded library /home/pi/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/lib/arm/libjfxwebkit.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$76(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/pi/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/lib/arm/libjfxwebkit.so: /home/pi/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/lib/arm/libjfxwebkit.so: falsche ELF-Klasse: ELFCLASS64 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryFullPath(NativeLibLoader.java:201)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:94)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:39)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.lambda$static$2(WebPage.java:130)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.<clinit>(WebPage.java:129)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.<init>(WebEngine.java:858)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.<init>(WebEngine.java:845)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:273)
    at application.Main$Browser.<init>(Main.java:38)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:22)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$83(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$61(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$59(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$60(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.runLoop(RunnableProcessor.java:92)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.run(RunnableProcessor.java:51)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application application.Main
```

ELFCLASS64 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)???
Whats wrong with libjfxwebkit.so?

Comment: HAve you tried following the recommendation and executed `execstack -c /home/pi/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/lib/arm/libjfxwebkit.so `?

Comment: yes, execstack finishes without errors, but has no effect. same error remains.

Comment: Ok, I will try to reproduce this later on my rig. In the mean time, this issue is very specific to the JavaFx Embedded SDK distributed by Gluon. Your best chance is probaly filing a bug with them.

Comment: thanks a lot for the effort!