# Run JavaFx on Raspberry ClassNotFound

Tags: java, javafx, raspberry-pi3, noclassdeffounderror

i try to start a jar on a raspberry pi. The jar is a gui application and it start a JavaFx stage.

I do all steps like here:
https://wimdeblauwe.wordpress.com/2017/08/26/using-javafx-on-raspberry-pi-3-with-gluon/
but with  the version 1.8.0_161.

Now i start the jar:

sudo /opt/jdk1.8.0_161/bin/java \
    -Djava.ext.dirs=build/armv6hf-sdk/rt/lib/ext \
    -jar Freelancer.jar

and receive the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Have some one a idea what is happen here?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you show what the JAVA_HOME variable is set to on your python

Comment: which java: /usr/bin/java

Comment: As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38103442/3956070) JavaFX for ARM doesn't support Swing.

Comment: Oh.. so there is no way to run this application on the Raspberry pi?

Answer (score 0):

Late answer (I had some problem today), but may be interesting for others:

In my case I have installed the open JRE and open JFX (free version of JavaFX):

```
apt-get install openjdk-8-jre-headless
apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
apt-get install openjfx
```

After that I have the same error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  ...`

That what was missing is: add the openjfx jar (`jfxrt.jar`) to the classpath (in my case it's located in `/usr/share/java/openjfx/jre/lib/ext/`):

```
java -cp my.jar:...:/usr/share/java/openjfx/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar com.be.HappyClass
```

After that I was happy ;-)